# "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation" when using CustomRoleProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, roleprovider

I've wrote a Custom Role Provider :

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {

            var rolesService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRoleService>();
            return rolesService.GetRolesForUser(username.ToInt());
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            var rolesService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRoleService>();
            return rolesService.IsUserInRole(username.ToInt(), roleName);
        }

        //....
}
```

and registered in `web.config` :

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" 
           type="PooyanTKD.Web.Infrastructure.CustomRoleProvider" 
           connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
           enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
           requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

And I've wrote a Custom Authorize Attribute :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class SiteAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(); //to avoid multiple redirects
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I decorate my Controller or action method with `[SiteAuthorize(Roles="Admins")]` after login I'm getting this error :

```
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

Source Error :

```
Line 14:             if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
Line 15:             {
Line 16:                 throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(); //to avoid multiple redirects
Line 17:             }
Line 18:             else
```

I've trouble finding out my problem and screwed me up, can anyone help me to figure out where is my problem?
**PS** : when I check value of `User.Identity.Name` in other view it's 0, also I check my authentication type in `web.config` :

```
<forms name="Sir1Afifi2013"
               cookieless="UseCookies"
               loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn"
               defaultUrl="~/Admin/Main"
               slidingExpiration="true"
               protection="All"
               path="/"
               timeout="20" />
</authentication>
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved my problem using redirecting Unauthorized user to another route this way :

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    action = "Index",
                    controller = "Home",
                    area = ""
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry dear @Sirwan Afifi